# What is the rate of new house construction in Auckland, New Zealand?

Tags: macroeconomics, data-request, housing

What is the rate of new house construction in Auckland, New Zealand, where the housing market seems to have gone to the roof? Assuming that the current high prices of Auckland houses are a result of less supply compared to demand (and not a bubble), is the number of houses to number of buyers going to stabilize anytime soon?

Also, if so many new houses are warranted in Auckland, is it also having high activity in the construction industry?

Comment: I don't know about NZ, but in Australia the ABS monitors these sort of metrics. Have you checked the NZ equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really serious about researching this data, I'd suggest contacting the Real Estate Institution of New Zealand: https://www.reinz.co.nz/reinz/public/reinz-statistics/reinz-statistics_home.cfm

As long as there are reasons to move to Auckland (more work etc.) and the supplied housing is not high enough to match the demand, the prices will continue to rise. This effect is visible in many major cities where the supply of housing is (for some reason like goverment rules or slow building) inelastic.